# How do I add a self signed root CA to Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: ubuntu, certificate, wget

I have an EC2 instance that I am trying to get a local wget to work.

I have my own CA set of keys,crt,pem  I have been using it to sign my company's certificate cert requests, and has been working well. On the webserver (AWS EC2) I have a standard Apache2 listener and it handles all the TLS. I Then load the CA into the browser and everything works fine.

I can even do this:

```
sudo openssl verify -CAfile myCA.pem internal.crt
internal.crt: OK
```

So I know everything is ok.
I now need to write code and call wget like this:

```
 wget https://internal.com
```

Response:

```
--2021-10-10 18:13:34--  https://internal.com/
Resolving internal.com (internal.com)... x.x.x.x
Connecting to internal.com (internal.com)|x.x.x.x|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify internal.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=myCA,OU=IT,O=myOrg CA,ST=FL,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
  ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches
requested host name ‘internal.com’.
```

I followed some instructions for adding my CA to ubuntu and I did this: taken from (https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate)

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra
sudo cp myCA.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra/myCA.crt
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

This is the output:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
rehash: warning: skipping myCA.pem,it does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL
1 added, 0 removed; done.
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20210119ubuntu0.21.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
done.
```

After running the above,  there is a myCA.pem in the /etc/ssl/certs  folder, but its a simlink to the myCA.crt

```
 myCA.pem -> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra/myCA.crt
```

And a .pem pointing to a .crt,  that can't be right can it?
Any suggestions?

Comment: `rehash: warning: skipping myCA.pem,it does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL` This should be a hint. Does myCA.pem have multiple certs or CRLs?

Answer (score 0):

The `.pem` file extension does not make it a PEM format file, same for the `.crt` extension (and any extension in general on Unix systems).

I ran into this issue on Debian when trying to import DER format certificates. I converted all certs to PEM format by running:
`openssl x509 -inform der -in infile.cer -out outfile.cer`

Then running the `sudo update-ca-certificates` command ran successfully.

Answer (score -1):

This message tells you the issue:

```
rehash: warning: skipping myCA.pem,it does not contain exactly one certificate
```

`myCA.pem` contains more than one certificate. Split the file into individual files, you can all them `myCA-1.pem`, `myCA-2.pem`, etc. Place them in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra/` and re-run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`

You will then see `/etc/ssl/certs` containing hashes symlinked to your certificate files and `wget` should then work as expected.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     13 Jul 13 10:40  6242745b.0 -> myCA-2.pem
```